# Closing JFrame with a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Im having problem with this code , it doesn't compile . Could you help me ?
I need to close the JFrame when i click the button

```
public class SlotMachine extends JFrame
{
    /*
     *
     */
    JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
        {
            this.dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

The error is = **The method dispose() is undefined for the type new MouseAdapter(){}**

I dont know how to get the SlotMachine object from the mouseClicked method

Comment: If it's not compiling and you don't know why, it would make sense to post the full error message, wouldn't it?

Comment: Side issue: never use a MouseListener for this -- instead add an ActionListener to the JButton for several reasons.

Comment: Get rid of `this`. That's it. Or else specify *which* `this` with `SlotMachine.this`.

Comment: Why should i use the ActionListener ?

Comment: Please see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `this.dispose();` the key here being that `this` refers to the inner class, the MouseListener, and MouseListener doesn't have a `dispose()` method.

Solution: get rid of `this`, and it should work, since the compiler will then look into the outer class if the inner class does not contain the method. Alternatively you could specify *which* this you mean: `SlotMachine.this.dispose();` will tell the compiler to call the method of the outer SlotMachine class.

Use an ActionListener on a JButton for several reasons:

- Default behavior of buttons is to be activated by spacebar press if the button has focus. This will not work for a MouseListener.
- Also an expected behavior is that if the button is disabled via `setEnabled(false)`, then pressing it should not cause the action to be fired. This does not work with MouseListener but does with ActionListener.
- You can easily share the ActionListener (or better yet, an AbstractAction) with other components including JMenuItems.

Comment: Thanks , but even if i use the ActionListener i have to use the SlotMachine.this.dispose()  ?

Comment: @Yuri: Yes of course. You're still using an anonymous inner class. Or else just use `dispose();`

Comment: Thanks i also studied this in the java doc and know it works :)